# как запустить функцию def (message) после нажатия на inline клавишу?

Tags: python, telebot, inline

После нажатия на клавишу должна запускаться функция, но никакого действия нет

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data in ['anonym', 'contact'])
def Suggestion_what(call):
    if call.data == "anonym":
        bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, "text", reply_markup=back)
        def anonym(message):
            a = message.text
            if a == "Back ⬅️" or a == "/start":
                bot.clear_step_handler
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "text", reply_markup=menu)
            else:
                chat = 'id'
                chat_id = int(chat)
                d = message
                bot.forward_message(chat_id, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
                bot.register_next_step_handler(d, anonym)
```

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, так сделать не получится. После нажатия на кнопку в функцию приходит `types.CallbackQuery`, а в **message** функцию должен прийти `types.Message`. Вам надо переписать код под **callback**.